# octave plot: how to set the correct position?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, octave

Here's what I met in octave:

```
x = -100 : 100
plot(x.^3)
```

But I get a graph like the following. It seems that the plot considers the point x = 100 to be x = 0, why? And how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`plot`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function with **one input** interprets that input as *y*-axis values, and assumes *x*-axis values are `1, 2, 3, ...`

To specify *x*-axis values use `plot` with **two inputs**:

```
plot(x, x.^3)
```